# List question from the boot automating the boring stuff

Tags: python, list

For the following three questions, let’s say spam contains the list ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'].

3. What does spam[int(int('3' * 2) // 11)] evaluate to?

Anyone knows the answer to this? TIA

Comment: You probably can answer this question by yourself, if you have a python interpreter - you don't need anyone's help in this.

Comment: So, where is the:  three following questions,

Comment: Is their any reason that you didn't evaluate the expression in the shell and see for yourself? That is easier than posting a question on Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's start from the middle of this expression. `'3' * 2` evaluates to `'33'`. This is because multiplication of a `str` object by a `int` object results in concatenating string with itself `n` times (providing you are multiplying by `n`).

`int('33')` is just `33` as an integer. When you feed `int` class a string it will try to convert it to a number, and will raise `ValueError` if it cannot convert (like `int('xfew')`). `int` has an optional second argument `base`, that specifies the numeric base in with string is written. For instance `int('ff', 16)` returns `255`. `base` is by default equal to `10`.

Operator `//` is an operator of integer division. Therefore `33 // 11` is equal to `3`. Note that `33 / 11` is equal to `3.0`, a `float`. Of course after converting it to `int` this will also be just `3`.

`int(3)` does really nothing. Just returns `3`. Concluding `spam[int(int('3' * 2) // 11)]` evals to `spam[3]`:

```
spam = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']
spam[int(int('3' * 2) // 11)] # returns 'd'
```